# Admin page select function

Tags: php

I am using this script to get the admin pages via this query string `?page=` once the admin is logged in.

Just needing a review, opinions

**Function:**

```
// GET PAGE FROM QUERY STRING
public function page_select($page) {
    $ext = '.php';
    $file = 'pages/'.$page.$ext;
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        return $file;
    }
    else {
        $file = 'pages/404'.$ext;
        return $file;
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["Cckiuas"]) && isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    if(isset($_GET['page'])) { $page = trim(htmlentities($_GET['page'])); }
    else { $page = 'dashboard'; }
    include($backend->get_base_url().INCLUDES."header.php");
    include($backend->page_select($page));
    include($backend->get_base_url().INCLUDES."footer.php");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the critical issues:

- You are vulnerable to directory attacks, I can get you to include any file by using the `../` to traverse up the directory structure, revealing details on your system:

  ```
  example.com/index.php?page=../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00
  ```

  The `%00` represents the [null byte character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (See **[Null Byte Injection](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection)**), which will terminate the string (thus ignoring your `.php` suffix). If I input that, I got all the users and passwords on the server (assuming the PHP user has read access, which it shouldn't, but most likely has).
- The `$ext` variable is redundant, are you by any chance going to stop using `.php` extension even though you won't stop using PHP? (Because, you know, the code is PHP)
- `htmlentities` is pointless if you aren't placing the target string in HTML. (And even if you were, `htmlspecialchars` is probably better)
- `INCLUDES` is magic. Immutable global variables (like constants) are still global!
- Consistent spacing and line-breaks - If you started with multiline in functions and control structures, stick with it.

Comment: Ok, so it would be better to call / link the page as normal for example `/page.php` and then pass a `query` to it, ie. `?action=manage` ? The idea behind this btw was to only call `header` and `footer` once with a side menu and just include the page content needed, for example `data tables`

Comment: The best thing is a very specific whitelist. (If the route matches this, it goes there). Don't try to do this part dynamically, at least until you know what you are doing.

Comment: Great advice, I'm changing it to a straight link to the page and then I'll use query strings to call specific functions within the page dependant on the action

Comment: The above would be similar to how wordpress does it btw

Answer (score 2):

I can't say much on the functionality, but I got a small comment on your if-statements:

#### Be consistent:

In your "Function" you have the blocks clearly cut out (linebreak & indention), In your "index.php" they are inlined.

I suggest you **always** do it like in your "Function":

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["Cckiuas"]) && isset($_SESSION["loggedin")) {
    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = trim(htmlentities($_GET['page']));
    }
    else {
        $page = 'dashboard';
    }
    //includes here
}
```

That btw. also applies for your usage of single and double quotes. Compare:

```
isset($_COOKIE["Ccuias"])
isset($_GET['page'])
```

**Decide on one**

Comment: Are there any security concerns doing this?

Comment: @CodeX "I can't say much on the functionality." My PHP is quite bad. in fact I don't actually use PHP anywhere. it's just a few bits I caught here and there. For security you'll have to wait on another review.